# Length of the data to decrypt is invalid. CryptoStream decrypting a string

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography

I have an encrypt and decrypt method that works on one site but when copying it over to another site I started to get the error: Length of the data to decrypt is invalid. I have had a look online and on all of the questions I could find here but none of them seemed to have a fix that works for me

the code encrypts without any issue but does not decrypt correctly. the error occurs on this line here

```
int decryptedByteCount = cryptoStream.Read(plainTextBytes,0, plainTextBytes.Length);
```

It is only a string that I am trying to decrypt

here is the full decrypt method:

```
 public static string Decrypt(string cipherText)
    {
        string passPhrase = "@Not Real Pass";        // can be any string
        string saltValue = "@Not real salt";        // can be any string
        string hashAlgorithm = "SHA1";             // can be "MD5"
        int passwordIterations = 2;                  // can be any number
        string initVector = "@1B2c3D4e5F6g7H8"; // must be 16 bytes
        int keySize = 256;                // can be 192 or 128

        // Convert strings defining encryption key characteristics into byte
        // arrays. Let us assume that strings only contain ASCII codes.
        // If strings include Unicode characters, use Unicode, UTF7, or UTF8
        // encoding.
        byte[] initVectorBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(initVector);
        byte[] saltValueBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(saltValue);

        // Convert our ciphertext into a byte array.
        byte[] cipherTextBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);

        // First, we must create a password, from which the key will be 
        // derived. This password will be generated from the specified 
        // passphrase and salt value. The password will be created using
        // the specified hash algorithm. Password creation can be done in
        // several iterations.
        PasswordDeriveBytes password = new PasswordDeriveBytes(
                                                        passPhrase,
                                                        saltValueBytes,
                                                        hashAlgorithm,
                                                        passwordIterations);

        // Use the password to generate pseudo-random bytes for the encryption
        // key. Specify the size of the key in bytes (instead of bits).
        byte[] keyBytes = password.GetBytes(keySize / 8);

        // Create uninitialized Rijndael encryption object.
        RijndaelManaged symmetricKey = new RijndaelManaged();

        // It is reasonable to set encryption mode to Cipher Block Chaining
        // (CBC). Use default options for other symmetric key parameters.
        symmetricKey.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

        // Generate decryptor from the existing key bytes and initialization 
        // vector. Key size will be defined based on the number of the key 
        // bytes.
        ICryptoTransform decryptor = symmetricKey.CreateDecryptor(keyBytes,initVectorBytes);

        // Define memory stream which will be used to hold encrypted data.
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(cipherTextBytes);

        // Define cryptographic stream (always use Read mode for encryption).
        CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream,
                                                      decryptor,
                                                      CryptoStreamMode.Read);

        // Since at this point we don't know what the size of decrypted data
        // will be, allocate the buffer long enough to hold ciphertext;
        // plaintext is never longer than ciphertext.
        byte[] plainTextBytes = new byte[cipherTextBytes.Length];

        // Start decrypting.
        int decryptedByteCount = cryptoStream.Read(plainTextBytes,
                                                   0,
                                                   plainTextBytes.Length);

        // Close both streams.
        memoryStream.Close();
        cryptoStream.Close();

        // Convert decrypted data into a string. 
        // Let us assume that the original plaintext string was UTF8-encoded.
        string plainText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(plainTextBytes,
                                                   0,
                                                   decryptedByteCount);

        // Return decrypted string.   
        return plainText;
    }
}
```

Let me know if the encryption method is needed as well

*EDIT*

As requested here is the encryption code:

```
public static string Encrypt(string plainText)
    {
        string passPhrase = "@Not Real Password";        // can be any string
        string saltValue = "@Not Real Salt";        // can be any string
        string hashAlgorithm = "SHA1";             // can be "MD5"
        int passwordIterations = 2;                  // can be any number
        string initVector = "@1B2c3D4e5F6g7H8"; // must be 16 bytes
        int keySize = 256;                // can be 192 or 128
        // Convert strings into byte arrays.
        // Let us assume that strings only contain ASCII codes.
        // If strings include Unicode characters, use Unicode, UTF7, or UTF8 
        // encoding.
        byte[] initVectorBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(initVector);
        byte[] saltValueBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(saltValue);

        // Convert our plaintext into a byte array.
        // Let us assume that plaintext contains UTF8-encoded characters.
        byte[] plainTextBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);

        // First, we must create a password, from which the key will be derived.
        // This password will be generated from the specified passphrase and 
        // salt value. The password will be created using the specified hash 
        // algorithm. Password creation can be done in several iterations.
        PasswordDeriveBytes password = new PasswordDeriveBytes(
                                                        passPhrase,
                                                        saltValueBytes,
                                                        hashAlgorithm,
                                                        passwordIterations);

        // Use the password to generate pseudo-random bytes for the encryption
        // key. Specify the size of the key in bytes (instead of bits).
        byte[] keyBytes = password.GetBytes(keySize / 8);

        // Create uninitialized Rijndael encryption object.
        RijndaelManaged symmetricKey = new RijndaelManaged();

        // It is reasonable to set encryption mode to Cipher Block Chaining
        // (CBC). Use default options for other symmetric key parameters.
        symmetricKey.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

        // Generate encryptor from the existing key bytes and initialization 
        // vector. Key size will be defined based on the number of the key 
        // bytes.
        ICryptoTransform encryptor = symmetricKey.CreateEncryptor(
                                                         keyBytes,
                                                         initVectorBytes);

        // Define memory stream which will be used to hold encrypted data.
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

        // Define cryptographic stream (always use Write mode for encryption).
        CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream,
                                                     encryptor,
                                                     CryptoStreamMode.Write);
        // Start encrypting.
        cryptoStream.Write(plainTextBytes, 0, plainTextBytes.Length);

        // Finish encrypting.
        cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();

        // Convert our encrypted data from a memory stream into a byte array.
        byte[] cipherTextBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();

        // Close both streams.
        memoryStream.Close();
        cryptoStream.Close();


        // Convert encrypted data into a base64-encoded string.
        string cipherText = Convert.ToBase64String(cipherTextBytes).ToString();

        //cipherText = cipherText.Replace("/", "");
        //cipherText = cipherText.Replace("\\", "");
        // Return encrypted string.
        return cipherText;
    }
```

Just a further bit of information, the string I am trying to decode for two test examples is 1008 and 1013, both of these are failing during decryption

Thanks

Comment: "encrypts without any issue" Who knows? Maybe the encryption is wrong, or encryption and decryption do not match.

Comment: by this I mean there are no visible errors and as this code is copy pasted from another site that works I feel it is safe to assume that the problem is not with the encryption but rather the decryption, however if you spotted something that could be causing a problem please do let me know what it is as I am running out of ideas on this one

Comment: opp's my mistake about the password (posted it at different times), I will have a look to make sure that the string is not being changed after the encryption

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure how you're encrypting your string, but as I can see that you're using a byte array of ascii values, I am going to assume that some of those encrypted characters are being encrypted as weird characters which could be messing with your returned string, for instance ' " ' would cause your string to end, meaning that the string being returned may not be of the right length.

Maybe do show your encryption method and we can find out for sure.

Comment: I Have added the encryption method as requested